# JAX-WS SEI - How to preserve date value that client sends

Tags: jax-ws

We have a JAX-WS SEI exposed to our clients and there is one XMLGregorianCalendar field in the request. The issue is when the client sends a date with UTC, the code in the service layer converts the date to its local timezone resulting in wrong date.

For ex, when a client running in EST sends 2012-12-27-05:00 to the server running in CST, at the server it gets converted to 2012-12-26. We want the value to be 2012-12-27. I have the following code which converts XMLGregorianCalendar to Date.

```
Date convertedDate = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

I would like to know how to preserve the date that client sends.

Answer (score 2):

Who has been actually doing the conversion to local timezone is your own code, in the "getTime" method. As you can see in debugging, your "xmlGregorianCalendar" still has the original time and timezone sent by the client (at least if the web service parameter type is "XmlGregorianCalendar", as if it were "Date" the conversion would indeed occurred in the service layer behind your code).

I have experienced this same issue and even though I'm here trying to help you, I haven't found a great solution. But I have found one:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

...

public Date webserviceDateToJavaDateKeepingOriginalTime(XMLGregorianCalendar webserviceDate) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(
            webserviceDate.getYear(),
            webserviceDate.getMonth(),
            webserviceDate.getDay(),
            webserviceDate.getHour(),
            webserviceDate.getMinute(),
            webserviceDate.getSecond());

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

By now it solved my problem, keeping the client time. I believe in the future I'll be forced to do something like to store in the database the client timezone in addition of its date and time, so I'll be able to show in the UI the original time or the converted (to local time) one, which will depend on the scenario.

I recommend you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices).

Comment: @Solomon you have answered the same as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer long time back but forgot to post my answer. I am posting now because it maybe helpful for somebody else in the future.

I commented my above code and added the below,

```
private Date getDate(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar) {

    /*
     * Date convertedDate = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar()
     * .getTime(); return convertedDate;
     */

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.set(xmlGregorianCalendar.getYear(),
            xmlGregorianCalendar.getMonth() - 1, xmlGregorianCalendar
                    .getDay());
    return cal.getTime();

}
```